# AngularJS - Remove query string and compare path

Tags: angularjs, query-string

```
$scope.currentLocationPath = $location.path();

$scope.configUserPath = '/configUser';

    http://myurl.com/#/configUser/

$scope.editUserPath = '/editUser';

    http://myurl.com/#/editUser/1

<div ng-hide="(currentLocationPath === configUserPath || currentLocationPath === editUserPath)>do something</div>
```

I am comparing path using current location. For url's without query string it works well but it is not comparing correct path for url's with query string as seen in edit user case.

How do I remove query string after editUser and compare it with currentlocation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in the case where you have the following URL :

```
http://myurl.com/#/editUser/1
```

Then `$location.path()` will return you : `/editUser/1` so you can split it on the character `/`, get the second element and add a `/` at the beginning (because `split` removes each `/`) like this :

```
'/' + $location.path().split('/')[1]
```

It will return you this :

```
/editUser
```

This also works in the case where you have the following URL (it will return you : `/configUser`) :

```
http://myurl.com/#/configUser/
```